# Why does CreateWindow() take a hInstance as an argument if was already provided when the window class was registered?

Tags: c, winapi

When registering a window class, it's necessary to fill in the `WNDCLASS`struct, which has a `hInstance` field:

```
typedef struct {
    UINT style;
    WNDPROC lpfnWndProc;
    int cbClsExtra;
    int cbWndExtra;
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    HICON hIcon;
    HCURSOR hCursor;
    HBRUSH hbrBackground;
    LPCTSTR lpszMenuName;
    LPCTSTR lpszClassName;
} WNDCLASS
```

Then, the window is created using `CreateWindow()` which takes in these parameters:

```
HWND CreateWindow(          
    LPCTSTR lpClassName,
    LPCTSTR lpWindowName,
    DWORD dwStyle,
    int x,
    int y,
    int nWidth,
    int nHeight,
    HWND hWndParent,
    HMENU hMenu,
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    LPVOID lpParam
);
```

---

- If the `hInstance` was provided with `WNDCLASS` when the class was registered, why is it necessary to provide a `hInstance` to `CreateWindow()`?
- Is the `hInstance` provided to `WNDCLASS` supposed to be same as the `hInstance` provided to `CreateWindow()`?
- If the `WNDCLASS` `hInstance` and the `CreateWindow()` `hInstance` are different, what do they mean?

---

Here is a sample program demonstrating class registration / window creation:

```
#include <windows.h>

LPSTR szClassName = "MyClass";
HINSTANCE hInstance;
LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
   WNDCLASS wnd;
   MSG msg;
   HWND hwnd;

   hInstance = hInst;

   wnd.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; //we will explain this later
   wnd.lpfnWndProc = MyWndProc;
   wnd.cbClsExtra = 0;
   wnd.cbWndExtra = 0;
   wnd.hInstance = hInstance;
   wnd.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); //default icon
   wnd.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);   //default arrow mouse cursor
   wnd.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND+1);
   wnd.lpszMenuName = NULL;                     //no menu
   wnd.lpszClassName = szClassName;

   if(!RegisterClass(&wnd))                     //register the WNDCLASS
   {
       MessageBox(NULL, "This Program Requires Windows NT", 
                        "Error", MB_OK);
       return 0;
   }

   hwnd = CreateWindow(szClassName,
                       "Window Title",
                       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, //basic window style
                       CW_USEDEFAULT,
                       CW_USEDEFAULT,       //set starting point to default value
                       CW_USEDEFAULT,
                       CW_USEDEFAULT,       //set all the dimensions to default value
                       NULL,                //no parent window
                       NULL,                //no menu
                       hInstance,
                       NULL);               //no parameters to pass
   ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);              //display the window on the screen
   UpdateWindow(hwnd);             //make sure the window is updated correctly

   while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))      //message loop
   {
       TranslateMessage(&msg);
       DispatchMessage(&msg);
   }
   return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   switch(msg)
   {
       case WM_DESTROY:
           PostQuitMessage(0);
           return 0;
   }
   return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

When a window class is registered it can be global (the `CS_GLOBALCLASS` style is set) or local to the module that registers it. For global classes the class names must be unique but for module-local classes the class names can clash - there's nothing stopping two DLLs registering window classes of the same name, and an executable could load both of those DLLs.

You therefore you need to tell the `CreateWindow` function which module's instance of the named class you want to use to create the window.

Comment: In other words, a (not global) window class is identified by the pair `hInstance-lpszClassName`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you mean : " If P creates a WNDCLASS struct X (P's hInstance is filled in), and two X's windows are registered,then the CreateWindow() need these two hInstances to distinguish these two X's windows " ?

Comment: So you're saying that even though the MSDN docs say "An application local class is any window class that an executable or .dll registers for its exclusive use", if a .dll registers a local class, the executable module can still create a window from the .dll's local class (assuming that the executable module has loaded the .dll of course).

Comment: @sadjezz: if module P registers classname X using P's hInstance, and module Q also registers the same classname X using Q's hInstance, then you have to tell CreateWindow() whether you want to use P's class or Q's class. That is why CreateWindow() has an hInstance parameter.

Answer (score 4):

For 32-bit (and 64-bit) Windows the hInstance may be used to identify the DLL that the window class belongs to. This is useful for global classes (see the answer of Jonathan Potter).

In this case the hInstance must be the handle of the DLL, not the hInstance argument from the WinMain() function.

See here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873

However I'm sure there is a second reason why this argument exists:

In 16-bit Windows this argument was definitely needed. When changing from 16- to 32-bit Windows Microsoft wanted to change as little as possible to remain source code compatibility. Therefore the hInstance argument has not been removed.

Comment: Yup, it mattered back in Win2 and Win3.

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: @Rainb: Link is now updated.

Answer (score 0):

`HINSTANCE hInstance;` in struct is an element of the `WNDCLASS` structure. This element of the sturcture can be initiated or assigned a value by creating an object of the structure `WNDCLASS`. While  `CreateWindow` is a function call where you have passed `HINSTANCE hInstance` as a paramter the function will use this parameter if not NULL to do some task.

To understand what HINSTANCE does click this [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/18/409205.aspx)

Comment: But CreateWindow() is able to get the hInstance by WNDCLASS. Why does it need hInstance as a parameter still?

Comment: HINSTANCE is an handle to the instance that contains the window procedure for the class so in every function definition you will find the same If the answer helps please select it as your answer by clicking on the arrow

Comment: link is broken :(

Answer (score -1):

The `hInstance` in the `WNDCLASS`-struct ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) is according to MSDN

> A handle to the instance that contains the window procedure for the class.

while for the `CreateWindow` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) call it says

> A handle to the instance of the module to be associated with the window.

As @IInspectable mentioned in the comments, this is relevant for [class lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574.aspx#system_locates_window) of application local classes:

> 1. Search the list of application local classes for a class with the specified name whose instance handle matches the module's instance handle. (Several modules can use the same name to register local classes in the same process.)
>      [...]

So essentially the local class lookup will only work if you set it to the same value.

Comment: I find some examples about WinMain() function and add it above,the same hInstance is assigned to WNDCLASS and CreateWindow().But thank you all the same

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine to assign the same one. It's just that you **can** assign different ones.

Comment: It is not just perfectly fine, it is **required** to pass the same module handle that registered an application local class to a call to `CreateWindow`, otherwise the call to `CreateWindow` fails. When instantiating an application global or system window class, the `hInstance` argument is ignored. See [How the System Locates a Window Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574.aspx#system_locates_window) for information on the procedure.